# Replacing a character with multiple characters

Tags: c++

I am making a simple encryption program, but I can't get the return function right. I want to replace the `[` with `\n`. But I can't get this to work. This is my current solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream in("file.txt");
std::ofstream out("result.txt");

std::string line;
while (!in.eof())
{
    std::getline(in, line);
    std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), "[", "\n");
    out << line;
}
```

Comment: Does this work instead? `std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), '[', '\n');` Note that I replaced the `"` with `'`

Comment: "\n" is one character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @melpomene Beat me, and I love that this comes up at least 2 times a day

Comment: This works, thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace " with '

This means you have to use character instead of string.
This is working at my side.

@Blaze